# Random Variable not being updated in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

While running this code to randomize some values I find that the all the cells have the same number. I believe I'm missing a standard concept but I can't seem to wrap my head around the issue.

```
Randomize
LWeekDay = Int((400 - 150 + 1) * Rnd + 200)
LWeekEnd = Int((600 - 200 + 1) * Rnd + 200)


For Y = 3 To 10

   For X = 2 To 8
       Cells(Y, X) = LWeekDay
   Next X
Next Y
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently only calculating `LWeekDay` once, and then using that value for every cell.

I assume you want to assign a new value every time through the loop:

```
Randomize
For Y = 3 To 10
   For X = 2 To 8
       LWeekDay = Int((400 - 150 + 1) * Rnd + 200)
       LWeekEnd = Int((600 - 200 + 1) * Rnd + 200)
       Cells(Y, X) = LWeekDay
   Next X
Next Y
```